# How to disable Angular 2 Universal - Server-side Rendering in VS 2015 projects

Tags: visual-studio, angular, yeoman-generator, angular-universal

I am using tempalte generate by yo aspnetcore-spa.
Some components refusing to work with Angular 2 Universal. How can I disable that feature in the project?